# How to reverse the order of integration in this iterated integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

How to reverse the order of integration in the iterated integral
$$
\int_{-2}^2 \int_{ 1 - \sqrt{2-x} }^{x/2} f(x, y) \, dy \, dx?
$$

My Attempt:

> Here
> $$ -2 \leq x \leq 2, \tag{1} $$
> and for each $x$ in this range, we have
> $$
> 1 - \sqrt{ 2-x} \leq y \leq \frac{x}{2}. \tag{2}
> $$

> The latter inequality in (2) is equivalent to
> $$
> 2y \leq x, \tag{3} 
> $$
> but as $x \leq 2$ from (1), so we have $2y \leq 2$, and hence
> $$
> y \leq 1, \tag{4}
> $$
> which together with the first inequality in (2) yields
> $$
> 0 \leq 1-y \leq \sqrt{2-x},
> $$
> which upon squaring yields
> $$
> (1-y)^2 \leq 2-x,
> $$
> and hence
> $$
> x \leq 2- (1-y)^2,
> $$
> which together with (3) yields
> $$
> 2y \leq x \leq 2- (1-y)^2. \tag{5}
> $$

> Now by (1) above as $-2 \leq x \leq 2$, so we have
> $$ -2 \leq -x \leq 2, $$
> which implies
> $$
> 0 \leq 2-x \leq 4, 
> $$
> and hence
> $$
> 0 \leq \sqrt{2-x} \leq 2,
> $$
> which implies
> $$
> -2 \leq -\sqrt{2-x} \leq 0, 
> $$
> and hence
> $$
> -1 \leq 1-\sqrt{2-x} \leq 1,
> $$
> in short, we have
> $$
> -1 \leq 1 - \sqrt{2-x}, 
> $$
> which together with the first inequality in (2) above yields
> $$
> -1 \leq 1 - \sqrt{2-x} \leq y,
> $$
> and hence
> $$
> -1 \leq y. \tag{6}
> $$

Thus from (4), (5), and (6), we have
$$
-1 \leq y \leq 1, \tag{7}
$$
and for each $y$ in this range, we have
$$
2y \leq x \leq 2- (1-y)^2. \tag{5}
$$

> Hence we have
> $$
> \int_{-2}^2 \int_{ 1 - \sqrt{2-x} }^{x/2} f(x, y) \, dy \, dx \ = \ \int_{-1}^1 \int_{2y}^{2- (1-y)^2} f(x, y) \, dx\, dy.
> $$

Is this solution correct and complete enough? Or, are there any problems?

If this solution is correct and complete, then my question is, while we have been able to deduce (7) and (5) from (1) and (2), we have not done the reverse. So does this not show merely that the former region is contained in the latter, without demonstrating the reverse inclusion?

Comment: Could you rephrase the last part of the question? I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent by Fubini since

$$ \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:-2\leq x\leq 2,1-\sqrt {2-x}\leq y\leq x/2\}\\
= \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:-1\leq y\leq 1,2y\leq x\leq 2-(1-y)^2\}
$$